# WPF App User Control

Tags: wpf, validation, authentication, dependency-injection, singleton

I have a WPF Application where I register many users in my apps inner Data Base. I have many classes that would like to query which user is logged in currently.

I wonder which is the best architecture for this kind of scenario.

So far I can think of:

- A Singleton object storing the current logged in User.
- Use Dependency Injection and pass an object containing all the login information for every class that needs it (and to some classes that won't need it directly, but might have to pass it along to another one later).

Singleton has its disadvantages, and DI could lead to many dependencies being shared all over the place and could be a maintenance nightmare on the furniture. I wonder if there is a better solution for this issue.

Comment: Why dont you inject your dependency into your base viewmodel.

Comment: Same problem applies. I will have to pass the dependency all over the place on each VM creation, and sometimes I just create it in the view's initialization code. I am not using a framework for automatic VM creation or anything like that. This will require me to change all 50+ ViewModels creations.